# Can I use the OpenCV Mat like a normal matrix?

Tags: opencv, linear-algebra

Can I use the opencv Mat like a normal matrix for multiply them, sum them and other things.

Like linear algebra. I tried but the compiler throws a Opencv's Exception.

Comment: According to [their documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), you can. What did you try? Can you show your code and the exception you got?

Comment: Code
 `cv::Mat a = cv::Mat( 3,3,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(2) );
  cv::Mat b = cv::Mat( 3,3,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(4) );
  cv::Mat c = a*b;`
Error `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) in gemm, file /opt/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 711
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /opt/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:711: error: (-215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2) in function gemm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. The error told me everything. My error was my matrix had not the correct type. I change the type to `CV_64FC1` and everything went right.